# iptables output chain rules for Tomcat redirect

Tags: tomcat, iptables

I'm using iptables to route traffic from 80 to 8080 and 443 to 8443 so I can run Tomcat as a non-root user.  It is all working except my OUTPUT chain rules.  I need the following rules so my single sign on works:

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

But with these rules, I can't connect to external sites.  How can I write these rules so only when I try to connect to my domain from my domain that it uses these, otherwise it ignores them?  Thanks!

Comment: Off-topic for so; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1- Add -d x.x.x.x to specify you local IP.

2- Use addrtype if you have several IPs: -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080

Regards,
 Diego